# pg_dump on Database throwing error 'out of shared memory'

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, pg-dump

Getting problem when taking backup on database contains around 50 schema with each schema having around 100 tables.

pg_dump throwing below error suggesting that to increase `max_locks_per_transaction`.

```
pg_dump: WARNING:  out of shared memory
pg_dump: SQL command failed
pg_dump: Error message from server: ERROR:  out of shared memory
HINT:  You might need to increase max_locks_per_transaction.
pg_dump: The command was: SELECT tableoid, oid, prsname, prsnamespace, prsstart::oid, prstoken::oid, prsend::oid, prsheadline::oid, prslextype::oid FROM pg_ts_parser
```

An updated of `max_locks_per_transaction` to 256 in `postgresql.conf` did not solve the problem.

Are there any possibilities which can cause this problem?

**Edited:(07 May, 2016)**

Postgresql version = 9.1

Operating system = Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

`shared_buffers` in `postgresql.conf` = 2GB

**Edited:(09 May, 2016)**

My postgres.conf

```
maintenance_work_mem = 640MB
wal_buffers = 64MB
shared_buffers = 2GB
max_connections = 100
max_locks_per_transaction=10000
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this problem by taking backup for all schema individually as size of database (be it no.of schemas or no.of tables) increases it's hard to take backup using pg_dump.

I have done following modification to the script to take schema-wise backup:

1. Before running `pg_dump`, list all database schemas into a file. So that we can iterate all schemas and take backup for a schema.

   Here is the command to list all schema to a file

   `psql <db_name> -o <output_file> < <sql_to_list_schema>`

   Here `sql_to_list_schema` contains

   SELECT n.nspname
       FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
       WHERE n.nspname !~ '^pg_' AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema';
2. Now read all lines of `output_file` and take backup of that schema

   `pg_dump <db_name> -f <backup_file> -i -x -O -R -n <schema_name_read_from_file>`

Comment: The [link](http://www.wisdombay.com/articles/article000013.htm) you provided for the script, doesn't work anymore...

Comment: You might want to use some extra params with to the `psql` command. This will easier reading of the names to a variable like: `--no-align --tuples-only --record-separator=" "`.

Answer (score 8):

You might need to increase `max_locks_per_transaction` even further.  Check the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-locks.html) for details on what this parameter means.  If in doubt, check how many tables you have and set `max_locks_per_transaction` to at least that much, then you should be OK.

Comment: Details? How many tables do you have, what are your configuration settings?

Comment: @PeterEisentraut, thanks for the tip. Initially not sure in which file that property has to be modified. Later got help from friends where to modify. `../data/postgresql.conf`

Comment: @Rao: And? Did it help?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
shared_buffers = 512GB
max_locks_per_transaction=10000
```

Please note that every env is different

Comment: I get this error: HINT:  This error usually means that PostgreSQL's request for a shared memory segment exceeded available memory, swap space, or huge pages. To reduce the request size (currently 563431931904 bytes), reduce PostgreSQL's shared memory usage, perhaps by reducing shared_buffers or max_connections.