# pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR: out of shared memory

Tags: postgresql

I have a database of 300GB and has 39000 tables in it. I am trying to create a dump and my postgresql config file looks like this:

```
max_locks_per_transaction = 50000                                                  
max_pred_locks_per_transaction = 256

shared_buffers = 4GB
maintenance_work_mem = 1024MB
work_mem = 10MB
```

Comment: Well, the error is pretty clear to me... Insufficient memory.

Comment: Do I need to increase the value any parameter??

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37089171/2408342) post.

Comment: What about for the data??

Comment: You should find out where `pg_dump` fails, that is, what statement it was executing. Could the problem be connected with an extension (PostGIS, ...)?