# pg_dump on very large table fails to lock the table

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I have defined a `LOG` table.
Then I created lot of child tables, one per minute, in the form of:

```
create LOG_20231209_1500 .. inherits LOG;
create LOG_20231209_1501 .. inherits LOG;
create LOG_20231209_1502 .. inherits LOG;
...
```

After many years a `count(*)` on LOG returns some billion. The number of child tables is: **357299**

But now it's time to have a backup, and **I'd like to have each table backed up in its own file**.

Unfortunately, using the following command:

```
pg_dump logdb -t LOG_20231209_1501 > LOG_20231209_1501.sql
```

raises the following error:

```
pg_dump: error: query failed: ERROR:  out of shared memory
HINT:  You might need to increase max_locks_per_transaction.
pg_dump: error: query was: LOCK TABLE public.LOG_20231209_1501 IN ACCESS SHARE MODE
```

even for a small table with 3000 records.
Note the a direct `select * from LOG_20231209_1501` produces results immediately. Also note that I've configured `max_locks_per_transaction=1024` in postgres.conf, with no success.

While I'm dumping **noone is using the database**: can I make pg_dump avoid locking the table and giving no modifications for granted?

PostgreSQL version is: 14.8

Comment: `ERROR:  out of shared memory.` have you researched the error message (there are a bunch of these questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37073166/pg-dump-on-database-throwing-error-out-of-shared-memory) and made sure you have enough RAM, swap, enough `shared_buffers`, etc.?

Comment: In `psql` what does `\d LOG_20231209_1501` return? Add that as text to your question text. Also add Postgres version.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver it returns a normal description of a normal table. 9 columns, 1 index btree, 2 check constraints, inherits: parent table. Is there any particular info I should be looking for? Added PostgreSQL version to OP which 14.8

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comments, **partial** answer to the problem is to increase `max_locks_per_transaction` to (at least) the number of objects involved in the query. In my case, since the parent table has 359299 child tables, I had to set `max_locks_per_transaction=360000` and `pg_dump` worked.

It is still a partial answer because `pg_dump` still tries to lock all the tables to dump structure or data of one single table; due to this it takes up to 1 minute to be executed, even if a simple `COPY tab INTO 'file' CSV` is immediate; this makes impractical to dump all tables using `pg_dump`.

Still I believe the correct way - if feasible - is to make `pg_dump` avoid locking at all.

Comment: You cannot do better than that. Sure, `pg_dump` could do something different, but there will be little enthusiasm for that. Creating 357299 inheritance children is not the correct way to use PostgreSQL. Its metadata structures and utilities are not designed for that, and you can expect them to become slow and inefficient.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I admit things went on unnoticed for a long time. But I believe the only different way to do it properly is to have different disjoint parent tables, one per year, or month, or day.. just to keep the number of inheritance children reasonable. I have to say for my particular scenario I never had the need to see data as a whole querying the parent table. I may rethink the schema. Thanks for the advice